# What does Domain in "Domain Model" means?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, domain-model, argouml

I have an assignment for school, where I have to create a domain model of a specific e-commerce site that delivers complete grocery bags to people's homes. (http://www.linasmatkasse.se/)

It's quite basic. Chose a bag, create account (with info), pay.

My question is, what exactly should be included in the model (in *general*)? In other words, where does the lines of the *domain* end? For instance, should **delivery** and **suppliers** be included? They aren't technically part of the website itself, by still play a role.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is domain

*Let us take some theme/subject. It could be grocery delivery, satellites, swallows observations, anything. Let us name this theme "AAA"*

<kbd>domain model for AAA</kbd> is a "profi IT" word for <kbd>model for AAA</kbd>. That's all.

All elements specific to AAA that you'll set in your model, belong to domain. I don't know, why the old good word *theme* is not used. It is a pity. But the term is already accepted.

So, delivery and suppliers are in your domain. And also much more specific words belonging to grocery. And to bags. And to people's homes - addresses, drive ways in and out - everything that is relevant to your theme.

The domain sets your vocabulary. And that one is really important - you should use the vocabulary used by your clients and not to invent new words, such as "domain" for "theme" :-)

And first you should define your **Use case diagram**, later- State machine diagram, Deployment diagram, Component diagram, Communication diagram, Sequence/Activity/Time/Interaction Overview diagrams, and at last - **class**, object and composite structure diagrams. You needn't make all of them, but SOME are necessary.

Comment: What exactly does AAA refer to?

Comment: Any Theme. Grocery delivery, satellites, swallows observations, anything.

Answer (score 2):

Every entity that models an entity in reality is a part of the domain. In your example, *delivery* and *suppliers* should be a part of the domain model. Basically any entity that has a defined behavior should be modeled as a part of the domain. Many times it seems like the domain model components aren't a part of the website and this is actually normal, the front-end is a way of viewing the domain model, it doesn't need to expose everything within the domain.
I usually find it easy to think about what entities are logical components of the business model in the real world and I only remove one if I find that it is redundant, unnecessary or can be encapsulated within another entity.

Answer (score 1):

### About the entities that are not the part of IT system

Do not ignore the pure human operations. On the contrary. Put them here, only their use cases will connect not actor-(sub)system, but actor-actor. And seeing them is very good for better planning the system as a whole. When ignoring them it is impossible to create a system good for user. The IT system is an integral component of the larger system, and we are creating the larger one really, with planning the support, processes, exchange of info, divisions and dependencies.

Too often had I problems with programmers who are blind to anything out of IT system border. And often it is impossible to make them think out of these borders. As a result, the system is blind to the real needs of the user, too. So we have that sad picture of user-hating software.

It is very useful to start to study the problem/domain/theme from entities that are out of the IT system, and to create firstly the diagram, that considers IT system as merely one of many blocks.

Comment: For this particular assignment, would you recommend also adding a generalization of specific items? Like the different types of grocery bags? Would that be sort of redundant in representing the domain?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by grocery bag. Is it a "buy cart" on site? Or something you are selling? In both cases they are parts of IT model, not of the human part of domain.

Comment: No, the grocery bag is a type of item. Item -> grocery bag -> Fruit bag. Does this add anything to model at all? Or is it a bit excessive?